# bs4 remove None tag after decompose

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to delete advertisment text from scraped data but after i decompose it i get error saying

> list index out of range

I think its becouse after decompose is blank space or somthing. Without decompose loop works ok.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.marketbeat.com/insider-trades/ceo-share-buys-and-sales/'

companyName = 'title-area'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr')

#  delete advertisment
soup.find("tr", class_="bottom-sort").decompose()

for el in table:
    print(el.find_all('td')[0].text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tag.extract()` to delete the tag. Also, delete the tag before you find all `<tr>` tags:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.marketbeat.com/insider-trades/ceo-share-buys-and-sales/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

#  delete advertisment
for tr in soup.select("tr.bottom-sort"):
    tr.extract()

table = soup.find_all("table")[0].tbody.find_all("tr")

for el in table:
    print(el.find_all("td")[0].text)
```

Prints:

```
...
TZOOTravelzoo
NEOGNeogen Co.
RKTRocket Companies, Inc.
FINWFinWise Bancorp
WMPNWilliam Penn Bancorporation
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong using `decompose()` you only have to pay attention to the order in your process:

```
#  first delete advertisment
soup.find("tr", class_="bottom-sort").decompose()

# then select the table rows
table = soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr')
```